# PHP setting and looping associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I populate the $_SESSION['products'] array from a file:

```
$myFile = '.\products.txt';
$handle = fopen($myFile, 'r');

while (!feof($handle))
{
    $prod = explode('|', fgets($handle));

    $_SESSION['products'] = array($prod[4] => array(
            'name' => $prod[0],
            'price' => $prod[1],
            'description' => $prod[2],
            'image' => $prod[3]));
}
```

Then I want to loop through it, printing all the names and prices:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $prodID=>$value) {
  echo $_SESSION['products'][$value]['name'];
  echo $_SESSION['products'][$value]['price'];
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: what is the output of `print_r($_SESSION['products'])`??

Comment: `Array ( [ylbulb] => Array ( [name] => 60W Yellow Bulb [price] => 7.95 [description] => Yellow Bulb description... [image] => ylbulb.png ) )` So all items are not being loaded into the array!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is, here you are overwriting the products array with every product, which means there will only ever be the last product present:

```
    $_SESSION['products'] = array($prod[4] => array(
```

Try appending to the array like:

```
$_SESSION['products'][$prod[4]] = array(
//                    ^^^^^^^^ set the key as the product ID here
        'name' => $prod[0],
        'price' => $prod[1],
        'description' => $prod[2],
        'image' => $prod[3]);
```

Also your foreach is wrong, try

```
foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $prodID=>$value) {
  echo $value['name'];
  echo $value['price'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't working. It giving an undefined index error and seems to multiplying the index with every page refresh.

Comment: Of course it will duplicate the array with a page refresh if you are calling this code again and again. `$_SESSION` data persists across pages, you should only populate the array from the file once.

Comment: ok thanks! i figured that out... however i still cant get to print anything due to the undefined index error

Comment: the two echos between the foreach loop

Comment: If the foreach is on a different page, be sure to call `session_start();` before trying to use any session data. If you don't call that before setting or getting session data, it will not be persisted.

Comment: They are on the same page... but no matter what I write, I cant seem to get access to the names and prices... the array is set up like this : `Array ( [0] => Array ( [fan ] => Array ( [name] => Standard Electric Fan [price] => 19.95 [description] => Fan description... [image] => fan.png ) ))`

Comment: I have edited the answer, which should solve the problem. The problem was you want the product ID as the key, you need to set that directly, see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check again how the [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) works. In your case, you can simply do the following:

```
foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $value) {
    echo $value['name'];
    echo $value['price'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is only printing the last item. For some reason, all items in the text file is not being loaded into the $_SESSION['products'] array!

Comment: See MrCode's answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $prodID=>$value) {
    echo $_SESSION['products'][$prodID]['name'];
    echo $_SESSION['products'][$prodID]['price'];
}
```